# Is there a better way to replace sas text string other than using tranwrd function

Tags: sas

I need to replace a series of text strings in sas. I have used the following below code to replace the strings and it works fine.

But still wondering, is there a better and robust way than this to replace the text strings?

**The input dataset has more than 100000 observations**

```
_PARAM = tranwrd(tranwrd(tranwrd( tranwrd(tranwrd(param,'/Erythrocytes ',''),'/Leukocytes ',''), '^3','!{super 3}' ), '^6', '!{super 6}'),'/uL', '/µL');
```

Thank you very much in advance

Rakesh.

Comment: Could you supply us some text to test with and the result you expect?

Comment: If you're familiar with regular expressions, that may be a better solution, but if you're not I would stick with tranwrd.

Comment: It also depends if this is all you want to do. If you just gave us a few example of your edits, this approach becoles realy inpractical and I also advise regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more readable, you could split the function calls across multiple lines like so:

```
param = tranwrd(param,'/Erythrocytes ', '');
param = tranwrd(param,'/Leukocytes '  , '');
param = tranwrd(param, '^3'           , '!{super 3}' );
param = tranwrd(param, '^6'           , '!{super 6}');
param = tranwrd(param,'/uL'           , '/µL');
_param = param;
```

To make it more robust you could consider converting it all to either upper or lower case (`upcase()`, `lowcase()`)to guarantee your `tranwrd()` function matched the strings (in case the input changes).

**EDIT** : You also seemed like you may have been concerned about performance.  These operations should be very fast even on a dataset with millions of observations.  If you are finding that this is not the case, then you may want to check the length of your `param` variable and ensure it is not excessively long.  Very long character variables will take comparatively longer when running character functions against them.

Comment: There are 4 missing semicolons in your sample.  (If only there were 6, I could fix it myself...)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get rid of text, i.e. replace with "", then you can simply use the *compress* function. So, for your cases where you want to get rid of "/Erythrocytes " and "/Leukocytes " you can use:

```
param = compress(param,'/ErythrocytesLeukocytes ');
```

or more explicitly:

```
param = compress(param,'/ErythrocytesLeukocytes ', '');
```

Comment: That command will also get rid of any occurrence of those letters. So it will remove all of the upper case and lower case E's. all of the t's and s's , etc.